# Splitting Strings from file and putting them into array causes program crash

Tags: c

I am trying to read a file line by line and split it into words. Those words should be saved into an array. However, the program only gets the first line of the text file and when it tries to read the new line, the program crashes.

```
FILE *inputfile = fopen("file.txt", "r");
char buf [1024];
int i=0;
char fileName [25];
char words [100][100];
char *token;

 while(fgets(buf,sizeof(buf),inputfile)!=NULL){

        token = strtok(buf, " ");
        strcpy(words[0], token);
        printf("%s\n", words[0]);
        while (token != NULL) {


            token = strtok(NULL, "  ");
            strcpy(words[i],token);
            printf("%s\n",words[i]);
            i++;

        }

    }
```

Comment: Thanks that worked, but can you explain why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After good answer from xing I decided to write my FULL simple program realizing your task and tell something about my solution. My program reads line-by-line a file, given as input argument and saves next lines into a buffer.

Code:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <errno.h>
#define _WITH_GETLINE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define assert_msg(x) for ( ; !(x) ; assert(x) )

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        FILE *file;
        char *buf, *token;
        size_t length, read, size;

        assert(argc == 2);

        file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
        assert_msg(file != NULL) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Error ocurred: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        }

        token = NULL;
        length = read = size = 0;

        while ((read = getline(&token, &length, file)) != -1) {
                token[read - 1] = ' ';

                size += read;
                buf = realloc(buf, size);
                assert(buf != NULL);

                (void)strncat(buf, token, read);
        }
        printf("%s\n", buf);

        fclose(file);
        free(buf);
        free(token);

        return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

For file `file.txt`:

```
that is a
text
which I
would like to
read
from file.
```

I got a result:

```
$ ./program file.txt
that is a text which I would like to read from file.
```

Few things which is worth to say about that solution:

1. Instead of `fgets(3)` I used `getline(3)` function because of easy way to knowledge about string length in line (`read` variable) and auto memory allocation for got string (`token`). It is important to remember to `free(3)` it. For Unix-like systems `getline(3)` is not provided by default in order to avoid compatibility problems. Therefore, `#define _WITH_GETLINE` macro is used before `<stdio.h>` header to make that function available.
2. `buf` contains only mandatory amount of space needed to save string. After reading one line from file `buf` is extended by the required amount of space by `realloc(3)`. Is it a bit more "universal" solution. It is important to remember about freeing objects allocated on heap.
3. I also used `strncat(3)` which ensures that no more than `read` characters (length of `token`) would be save into `buf`. It is also not the best way of using `strncat(3)` because we also should testing a string truncation. But in general it is better than simple using of `strcat(3)` which is not recommended to use because enables malicious users to arbitrarily change a running program's functionality through a buffer overflow attack. `strcat(3)` and `strncat(3)` also adds terminating `\0`.
4. A `getline(3)` returns token with a new line character so I decided to replace it from new line to space (in context of creating sentences from words given in file). I also should eliminate last space but I do not wanted to complicate a source code.

From not mandatory things I also defined my own macro `assert_msg(x)` which is able to run `assert(3)` function and shows a text message with error. But it is only a feature but thanks to that we are able to see error message got during wrong attempts open a file.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is getting the next token in the inner while loop and passing the result to strcpy without any check for a NULL result.

```
while(fgets(buf,sizeof(buf),inputfile)!=NULL){

    token = strtok(buf, " ");
    strcpy(words[0], token);
    printf("%s\n", words[0]);

    while (token != NULL) {//not at the end of the line. yet!
        token = strtok(NULL, "  ");//get next token. but token == NULL at end of line
        //passing NULL to strcpy is a problem
        strcpy(words[i],token);
        printf("%s\n",words[i]);
        i++;
    }
}
```

By incorporating the check into the while condition, passing NULL as the second argument to strcpy is avoided.

```
while ( ( token = strtok ( NULL, "  ")) != NULL) {//get next token != NULL
    //if token == NULL the while block is not executed
    strcpy(words[i],token);
    printf("%s\n",words[i]);
    i++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sanitize your loops, and don't repeat yourself:

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{

    FILE *inputfile = fopen("file.txt", "r");
    char buf [1024];
    int i=0;
    char fileName [25];
    char words [100][100];
    char *token;

 for(i=0; fgets(buf,sizeof(buf),inputfile); ) {
        for(token = strtok(buf, " "); token != NULL; token = strtok(NULL, " ")){
            strcpy(words[i++], token);
            }
        }
    return 0;
    }
```